# Solr store index in HBASE

Tags: solr, hbase

I have a SOLR index and I'm looking for the most appropriate way to store it in HBase.
Now SOLR is in cloud and the index is stored locally, but it's big and HBase seems to be a good step ahead.

I know about Solbase, Lily and Nutch but never used any of them.
And I don't know what to do - chose something from that list, or something else, or just look for some way to use SOLR with Hbase directly?

Any experiments would take really long (cause with small data perfomance can be nice, but bad with big, so I need to reindex all data in new system first).

Comment: So did you figure it out? Even I had gone through various posts and tutorials but yet could figure out the best and easy way for this. Most notably there are lots of theories, comparison and ppts; no hands on examples. Could any one refers me to some hands on example on this- mostly on HBase, Solr, MapReduce and Web App Integration(PHP or Java)!

Comment: @Dexter I've tried SolBase, but the project seems abandoned, I could not use it cause of code errors and had no time to fix them properly. So, if u have something (anything), please share it to me. By the way, I suggest u to ask on [SOLRs mail list](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Solr-User-f472068.html), lot of people from there don't use SO

Comment: Thanks for the reply Nick. I would check SOLRs mail list. Also I'd definitely share if I find something useful down the line.